# Reload a val in clojure

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have a datomic connection value defined alongside some helper functions:

```
(def uri "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/dab")

(defn delete-db [] (d/delete-database uri))
(defn create-db [] (d/create-database uri))

(def conn (d/connect uri))
```

The problem is if I call delete-db and then create-db the connection in the "conn" value is dropped. So I need a way to be able to 'reload' the conn value after doing the delete/create cycle. Given the immutable nature of "def values" how can I do this?

I came across this: http://www.rkn.io/2014/02/10/datomic-antipatterns-connnnn/ which discusses the reasons not to use conn as a value, however it only makes sense when doing query. I am passing conn into function to do transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend two solutions to your problem:

1. Simple: wrap your connection value into `atom`. It makes it explicit that it might change with time and it provides you clearly defined characteristic of changes. You can expose a clean API functions like `open-conection` and `close-connection` that will manipulate the state of the atom.
2. Sophisticated: you can use a library/framework which handles lifecycle of your runtime resources. The most popular (and quite orthogonal approaches) are [Component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) and [Mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount).

You can also use `alter-var-root` but I would use it as a last resort method and treat it as a hack.